# Getting difference between summs

Tags: mysql, summary

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT YEAR(date_entered), MONTHNAME(date_entered), SUM(amount)
FROM opportunities
GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered);
```

which brings back this data

```
"year(date_entered)","monthname(date_entered)","sum(amount)"
"2009","March","9038714.77"
"2009","April","2205819"
"2009","May","9706852.6"
```

what i need to do is show differences? example march was 903, april was 220 so difference will be 680, and so on, so latest sum value minus precious months value?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you can guarantee the order of the result set, you can "cheat" with user variables.  Otherwise, you can join it to itself, and calculate the sum more cleanly based on ON conditions.

Comment: Any reason to do this in mysql? it would be trivial to do on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query with variables, like this:

```
SELECT
  year_entered, month_entered,
  total_amount-@last_sum diff,
  @last_sum:=total_amount total_amount
FROM (
  SELECT
    YEAR(date_entered) year_entered,
    MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered,
    SUM(amount) total_amount
  FROM
    opportunities
  GROUP BY
    YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)
  ORDER BY
    YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)
  ) s,
  (SELECT @last_sum:=null) r
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f28/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT year_entered, 
       month_entered,
       IFNULL(amount - @n, 0) amount_diff,
       @n := amount current_amount
  FROM
 (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) year_entered, 
         MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered, 
         SUM(amount) amount
    FROM opportunities
   GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)) q, 
 (SELECT @n := NULL) n
```

Comment: Great. What is stopping you from doing so?